# Create objects into model foreach query

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple model like:

```
public class StatisticsModel
{
     public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Time {get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add to that model each register of foreach clause like:

```
 StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
 foreach(var i in tasks)
 {
     var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
     var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
     var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();

     model.TaskId = i.TaskId;
     model.Name = i.Name;
     model.Time = test
 }

 var final2 = model;
```

So as you can see I assign TaskId, Name and Time to model, but when foreach finish it only add last register to model. How can I create one object foreach `task`(in my case) in model? I try something like `model.Add()`but add method donesn't exists in my model. What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: You overwrite the value of model in foreach and get only the last value.  Set the model as a property in task.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, you just need a list of models:

```
List<StatisticsModel> models = new List<StatisticsModel>();
foreach(var i in tasks)
{
    StaticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();

    var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
    var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
    var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();

    model.TaskId = i.TaskId;
    model.Name = i.Name;
    model.Time = test;

    models.Add(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add multiple attributes to a single thing: you must have multiple `StatisticsModel` objects for this.

For example, you could use a `List<StatisticsModel>`:

```
var models = List<StatisticsModel>();
foreach(var i in tasks) {
    StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
    var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
    var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
    var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();
    model.TaskId = i.TaskId;
    model.Name = i.Name;
    model.Time = test;
    models.Add(model);
}
```

If you prefer LINQ-style queries, you could eliminate the loop altogether:

```
var models = tasks.Select(i => {
    var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
    var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
    var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();
    return new StatisticsModel {
        TaskId = i.TaskId
    ,   Name = i.Name
    ,   Time = test
    };
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `List<StatisticsModel>` at the top, that way you can add to it in your foreach:

```
List<StatisticsModel> models = new List<StatisticsModel>();

foreach(...)
{
    ...
    StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
    // Assign props
    models.Add(model);
}
```

Or even better; since you are actually just transforming the task collection, just use a select:

```
List<StatisticsModel> models = tasks.Select(task => {
   //The foreach contents
   StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
   // Assign props
   return model;
}).ToList(); //ToList not necessary; eager enumeration is not ideal most of the time but included since you seem to want a list
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your `foreach` loop overwrites the model.  Store it in a `List`:

```
List<StatisticsModel> allModels = new List<StatisticsModel>();
foreach(var i in tasks)
{
    StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
    var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
    var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
    var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();

    model.TaskId = i.TaskId;
    model.Name = i.Name;
    model.Time = test
    allModels.Add(model);
 }

 var final2 = allModels;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a list (or some other  collection) to get a list of the models.  Here's the code below

```
 List<StatisticsModel> models = new List<StatisticsModel>();
 foreach(var i in tasks)
 {
     var parameters = ToDataTable(tasks.Select(x => new { i.TaskId, i.Name }).ToList());
     var timeOfTasks = db.ExeSQLParamTable("usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime", parameters, "@ProjectTimeWorkedTableType");
     var test = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows select (int)dr["TaskName"]).FirstOrDefault();

     StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();
     model.TaskId = i.TaskId;
     model.Name = i.Name;
     model.Time = test

     models.Add(model);
 }

 var final2 = models; //list of model
```